# Flexbox Columns: Vertically Aligning the Last Element

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an unequal amount of content in three flexbox columns, but I want the buttons that appear at the bottom of each column to line up. How can I do this?

## The code I'm using <sup><sub>([Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gprVqy))</sub></sup>

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px 0;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.col {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}
.col:first-child:after,
.col:last-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 33.33%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #000;
}
.col:last-child:before {
  left: 66.67%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Foo</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Bar</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Bar</p>
    <p>Baz</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

## What I am getting right now

[image: Buttons that are not aligned]

## What I want to get

[image: Buttons that are aligned]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```css
.col {
    display: flex;          /* Magic begins */
    flex-direction: column; /* Column layout */
    align-items: center;    /* Center contents horizontally */
}
button {
    margin-top: auto;       /* Push to the bottom */
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px 0;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.col {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.col:first-child:after,
.col:last-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 33.33%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #000;
}
.col:last-child:before {
  left: 66.67%;
}
button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Foo</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Bar</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Bar</p>
    <p>Baz</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that margin between paragraphs will no longer collapse, so you may want to reduce it.